# Convertir fecha UNIX timestamp a date

Tags: javascript

Cuando me llega la información a mi API llega con el formato Unix `TimeStamp`

Por ejemplo: `1535440000` necesito convertir este formato a `YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ` por ej: `2018-05-31T16:49:27.698Z`.

Estoy trabajando en JavaScript y MongoDB. ¿Existe alguna función para realizar esta transformación?

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En `javascript` multiplicas el valor por 1000 para obtenener el tiempo en milisegundos y obtienes con `toISOString` la fecha en formato formato ISO8601.

```js
var data = 1535440000;
var date = new Date(data * 1000).toISOString();
alert(date);
```

Origen [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35890537/5675636).

Comment: Gracias esto era lo que estaba buscando. Un saludo.